# How to Optimise a JPA Query

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

I have three entities as follows:

```
public class EntityA
{
    private Long id;
    //Getters and setters
}

public class EntityB
{
    private Long id;
    private EntityA entitya;
    //Getters and setters
}

public class EntityC
{
    private Long id;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private EntityB entityb;
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Now, given an Instance of EntityA, i want to get a list of EntityC. I have two options available to me currently. I don't know which one is more optimized. The options are:

```
1.
select c from EntityC c where c.entityb in (select b from EntityB b where b.entitya = :entitya)
```

2.
Add a new property to EntityB

```
private Set<EntityC> entityCCol;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="entityb")
public Set<EntityC> getEntityCCol()
{
   return entityCCol;
}

select b from EntityB a join fetch a.entityCCol b
```

Which of these two queries is easier and optimized?

Comment: What about `select c from EntityC c where c.entityB.entityA = :a`? if you create this query, and `create index IX_B_A on entityB(entityA, id)` the resulting query will be fast enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the size of the collection.  For small collections I would use the relationships in the object model.  More from a design/usability perspective than performance, it is more object-oriented.  I wouldn't join fetch it though, just access the model normally.  You should probably also have a relationship from A to B to make your model more useful.

For the query in #1, your query is not very efficient using the sub-selects, just use a join,

select c from EntityC c where c.entityb.entitya = :entitya

Answer (score 2):

i think all the queries with interpreted into SQL queries, these are only different styles, you do not have to think about it. all the queries will interpreted into theta style. I do not think, there is a performance difference, it is only a personal choice. here is a very fresh article about SQL query style [MySQL joins: ON vs. USING vs. Theta-style](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/mysql-joins-on-vs-using-vs-theta-style) , I hope this link helps you somehow.

Comment: My concern on the two queries above and any other suggested query is performance. Guess what, in the database EntityB have about 20,000 records and each of the 20,000 records have at least 200 records i.e. EntityC.